# jQuery: Giving an id at the same time of element creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

Using a 'for' loop, let's say I want to make 4 different 'p' elements in the body with 4 different IDs. I approached the problem as follows:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $("body").append(document.createElement("p"));
    $("p").attr('id', 'paragraph' + i);
}
```

This was a very silly mistake on my part, heres why:

Every time the loop increments, it creates another p element, which is what I want it to do. However, it assigns ALL the p elements to the latest value of 'i'. So when the loop is executed all of of p elements would have a value of four.

My question is: Is there a way to assign the 'p' element's ID to the current value of 'i' when the 'p' element is appended?

---

To be clear, this is my goal:

```
<p id="paragraph1"></p>
<p id="paragraph2"></p>
<p id="paragraph3"></p>
<p id="paragraph4"></p>
```

But doing it through jQuery without editing the actual HTML file.

Comment: Why do you need your elements to have IDs? You can't assign an ID without first getting a reference to the element and once you have that the ID is no longer required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's selector problem

```
$("p:last").attr('id', 'paragraph' + i);
```

will select last p html tags and give it the current i value

check this [link](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Create element and set attribute first

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var p= document.createElement("p"); 
    p.setAttribute("id", "paragraph" + i);
    $("body").append(p);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `.setAttribute()` to set the "id" of a DOM element node. `p.id = "paragraph" + i;` will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.createElement()`, use jQuery:

```
$("body").append($("<p/>", { id: "paragraph" + i }));
```

When you create an element with jQuery by passing in the HTML fragment for the element you want, you can add an object that provides properties for the new object. That can include a wide variety of things, including native DOM stuff as well as things like jQuery event handlers. For example, you can add text to your paragraph:

```
$("body").append($("<p/>", {
  id: "paragraph" + i,
  text: "Hello I am paragraph number " + i
}));
```

Comment: I suspect this was downvoted because most people don't know that the jQuery function can do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/7snh10zz/

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $("body").append("<p id='paragraph" + i + "'>Paragraph " + i + "</p>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One more way to do it https://jsfiddle.net/7snh10zz/2/

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   $("body").append(document.createElement("p"));
   $("p:last-child").attr('id', 'paragraph' + i).text("Paragraph " + i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery to instantiate the new element, since jQuery is already being used?

Comment: *"with the solution"* - I think you mean with **a** solution. But I admire your confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mean,`$("p")` select all created elements and give the id.
In 1st iteration,your body has one p element with id paragraph1.
In 2nd iteration, your body has two p elements with ids paragraph2.It override the first `<p>` tag's id.
In 3rd iteration, your body has three p elements and your code select these three elements and give id of paragraph3 to all tags.
In these way, the last iteration cause your body to have four p elements with ids of paragraph4.
You can fix by using this code.

```
    function appendText() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            var txt = "<p id='paragraph"+i+"'></p>";
             $("body").append(txt);
        }       
    }
```